# Remove repeated words from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I have a string like `"one two one three"` or `"one|two|three|two"`.

Any ideas on removing repeated words from the string in C.

Comment: Yeah. Write a function that does it.

Comment: Try something yourself. Ask for help if you run into problems.

Comment: If this is homework or an interview question, the convention on this site is to mark it as such using tags.

Comment: I hate when questions are closed because they are not constructive, the point of a question is not to help others but to get an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Psuedocode:

```
hare=tortoise=str;  /* let str = your starting string. */
while (hare != NULL):
  if !(been_seen(current_word(hare))):
    word_copy(tortoise, hare);
    advance_to_next_word(hare);
  advance_to_next_word(hare);
*tortoise = NULL;
```

Explanation: The fast-moving "hare" pointer advances through the string, one word at a time.  When it encounters a previously unseen word, copy that word to the trailing "tortoise" pointer, which is then advanced to the end of that word.  This destructively modifies the original string.

To implement this approach, you would need to implement `advance_to_next_word()` (which would have to detect word edges marked by one of your delimiter characters), `word_copy()`, and most importantly `been_seen()`, a function which must return `false` the first time it is passed any word as an argument, then `true` on any subsequent call with the same argument.  Any associative array (dictionary) data structure will do.